Using a custom verbatim environment
I have my own Python environment called PYT. org exports to latex as follows:
#+begin_PYT
__elem__ = 1
#+end_PYT


generates
\begin{PYT}
\uline{\uline{elem}} = 1
\end{PYT}

which prints literally:
\ uline {\ uline{elem}} = 1
I dont want org transcoded contents but verbatim contents.
Is there some way to tell org?

Translate the headlines as it is doing
Leave the contents alone


Do you want that for PYT special blocks only or for any special blocks? You probably have to modify the function org-latex-special-block along the lines of org-latex-example-block.

I think a workaround is to use EXAMPLE blocks which include the contents as-is and mark them as PYT environments:
#+ATTR_LATEX: :environment PYT
#+BEGIN_EXAMPLE
contents
#+END_EXAMPLE


Tnx Nick. Thats ½ way to what I was hoping for -- reduce my current 4 line baggage to 2. You have 3. My current 4 line is (1) \begin_export latex (2)  \begin{PYT} .. stuff... (3) \end{PYT} (4) \end_export. [You need to add + after the '#']

Thanks - I'm going blind in my old age...

You can get it down to 2 but you have to modify Org mode - see my comment. Not worth it in my opinion, unless you generalize it and make it optional for any special block. I'd just use an abbrev or similar.
